# \pgfpagesuselayout with rounded blocks

Tags: beamer

I use \pgfpagesuselayout to print shrink pdf of my beamer presentation. But the rounded option of blocks produce a blank line between the title and body. The problem only occured with xelatex engine. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=white,bg=blue}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]% This rounded option cause the problem.

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
\begin{document}

\frame{

\begin{block}{test}
This is a test.
\end{block}

}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output picture]

Comment: Works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nQ6b.png Can you please add how you compile your document, which pdf viewer you use and also add you log file so we can see which version of beamer etc. you use

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes. The problem only occur under xelatex engine. I open the pdf file use the native preview app of Mac. ''This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)''. I have edited the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't use xelatex with beamer. If you want an unicode aware engine, use lualatex instead.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Xelatex is almost twice as fast as lualatex for my big Chinese tex document.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use xelatex with beamer - there are a lot of other problems, not just a missing shading.

I suggest to switch to `lualatex` if you need an unicode aware engine.

---

That being said, if you really must use `xelatex`, you could work around the problem by replacing the normal beamer blocks with tcolorboxes. You can use the `tcolorbox` inner theme for this:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[c]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=white,bg=blue}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]

\useinnertheme[rounded]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{test}
This is a test.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This done the job. Can we adjust the title size and the sep between title and body in tcolorbox？

Comment: @MiGang You can adjust everything in tcolorbox. It is a very flexible package.